# ERROR: App can't run on your PC. Tried all options found on internet to fix

Tags: windows-10, permissions, zip, gaming

I downloaded a version of the Sims to my Windows 10 PC just an offline play zip file. Keep getting the error message App can't run on PC. I have tried every solution I can find as to why this keep popping up. I'm at a loss. Maybe I am missing something small & I'm just an idiot but any suggestions would really help :)

Comment: When you unzip it, what are you using? Is it unzipping into it's own folder? Is it an .exe file you are trying to run from (Setup.exe), does it show an Icon? Is your Windows 10 64-bit or 32-bit (x64 ; x32). If it is a 32-bit, you might be trying to run a x64 software which Windows x32 cannot run.

Comment: I downloaded it through MEGAsync & then extracted it to my PC. As far as I know I'm running on 64bit In my system info it says "64 Bit operating system, ARM based processor" but in my compatibility admin it says (32-bit) in the top. Not sure if one has to do with the other I honestly haven't worked with windows in years so I am a little lost.  The program is going into the folder for the MEGAsync downloads

Comment: If you press the Winkey+Pause/Break you will open Windows system properties window. On the right it should give information about your system.

Comment: yes it is 64 bit os

Comment: Go into the folder where you extracted the .zip file and you should find an .exe program, most are called setup.exe. If you right-click the file choose properties and look for a tab which says Details, it should give you information about the file. The more tabs you find and read the better, they can give you more insite on the program. If you find an .msi instead right-click on the .msi file and choose Install. __It may be that Windows Defender is not allowing it run.__

Answer (score 1):

The App is made for another platform. Please verify the specification/information on the page from where you downloaded the file (or post the link here for a more specific answer).

Just in addition:

- A zip file can contain anything, it doesn't say anything about the platform the App is for.
- It doesn't look like a permission issue at all.

## Update

Look here: https://steamunlocked.net/the-sims-4-free-download/
and the "HOW TO RUN GAME!!.txt", as described in the first comment.

Comment: https://mega.nz/#!rl0T3Y4T!qa_fKn2is5pEkbGW9ocy1VjdTx753K2o3T8rDvfvVWc               That is the link.

Comment: Thank you, but this is just the file download link, and I need the link where this file is linked from (describing the file/app).

Comment: I clearly have no absolute idea what I am doing. So it was actually basically purchased from someone & I am assuming that may prevent me from actually getting you that information???

Comment: The point is that the App was made for another platform. Unless you cannot fix that with Windows Compatiblity settings (right click on EXE file, Compatiblity), you won't be able to run the App on our PC. Sorry to say.